# Moving attributes with Jquery in DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the href attribute of an element, fairly deep inside the tree.
This is the code i'm so far tweaking

```
$('.widget-pSidebar > ul > li > article > section > div > article > a').each(function () {
        var path = $(this).parent().find('footer').children().children().attr('href');
        alert(path);
        $(this).attr('href', path);
    });
```

while this is the tree

```
<a>
    <img>
</a>
<footer>
    <h1>
        <a>
    </h1>
```

I want to take the href from the last  and put it into the first one.

EDIT: I remade the code, and i can access a, but unfortunately i copy the same link over & over again.

Comment: Can you show us your entire HTML structure please.

Comment: Would posting just the section which all are in be enough?

Comment: From the excerpt you showed, it seems like your code should work. Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Rentonie a couple of sections would be best.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be easy, add an id on each link.

```
<a id="link-to">
    <img>
</a>
<footer>
    <h1>
        <a id="link-from">
    </h1>
```

And then do

```
var link = $('#link-from').attr('href');
$('#link-to').attr('href', link);
```

Done.

-- *Edit* --
If we have a list or something like

```
<div class='list-item'>
    <a class="link-to">
        <img>
    </a>
    <footer>
        <h1>
            <a class="link-from">
        </h1>
```

And then :

```
$('.list-item').each(function () {
    var path = $(this).find('.link-from')[0].href
    $(this).find('.link-to')[0].href = path;
});
```

Done :)

Comment: He probably has multiple repetitions of this, so it needs to be classes, not IDs.

Comment: I have a list, and i want to edit each one of them, so i'm sure if doing that way, i'm taking each different link.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some classes to your html ?

Then you can write something like this:

```
 <a class="destiny">
   <img>
 </a>
 <footer>
   <h1>
     <a class="source" href="href1"></a>
   </h1>
</footer>
```

*: you can do this with ID's as well.

Then your JS could be something like this:

```
$('.destiny').attr('href',$('.source').attr('href'));
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NX29W/

You have to inspect the result of the fiddle.

Comment: he has multiple of these things, that's why he's using `.each()`. Your answer will update all of them to the same value.

Comment: He have multiple <footer> on his markup ? Then he should re-think about the structure of his html...

Comment: It's the way orchard structured it. I just pointed that i wanted the X element in the "footer" of the list item.

Comment: I really dont get what you need. You want to read the href of the anchors you have on the footer and assign them to anchors with images you have on the "body" (not the footer).

Is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Give them an identifier like

```
<a class="anchor1">
    <img>
</a>
<footer>
    <h1>
        <a>
    </h1>
</footer>
```

then

```
$('(etc..) > a.anchor1').each(function () {
var path = $(this).next().find('a').attr('href');
alert(path);
$(this).attr('href', path);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    var path = $(this).next().children().first().children().first().attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', path);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7YHy/